# label every other tick with ggplot ggh4x nested label

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, xticks, ggh4x

I'm trying to remove labels every other tick starting from 2, I'm unable to do this when I use nested labels with `ggh4x` package.

My second question: Is there a way to move "AUG" and "SEP" to the left (align left) and add more space between the days and the mon ("AUG", "SEP") variable?

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)


datz <- structure(list(dnum = c(19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 
                        27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
                        10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
                        23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L), value = c(1, 0, 2, 
                                                                            0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 70, 127, 76, 71, 45, 37, 32, 30, 
                                                                            24, 18, 15, 6, 13, 6, 8, 6, 5, 2, 3, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0, 
                                                                            2, 1, 0), mon = c("AUG", "AUG", "AUG", "AUG", "AUG", "AUG", "AUG", 
                                                                                              "AUG", "AUG", "AUG", "AUG", "AUG", "AUG", "SEP", "SEP", "SEP", 
                                                                                              "SEP", "SEP", "SEP", "SEP", "SEP", "SEP", "SEP", "SEP", "SEP", 
                                                                                              "SEP", "SEP", "SEP", "SEP", "SEP", "SEP", "SEP", "SEP", "SEP", 
                                                                                              "SEP", "SEP", "SEP", "SEP", "SEP", "SEP", "SEP", "SEP", "SEP"
                                                                            )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -43L))



ggplot(data=datz,mapping = aes(x = interaction(dnum,mon),y = value)) +geom_bar(stat = "identity",width = 0.25)+ 
  scale_x_discrete(guide = "axis_nested") + theme_classic() + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0),breaks = seq(0,150,10))+
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this (set breaks on even observations by `interaction(datz$dnum,datz$mon)[c(T,F)]`):

```
ggplot(data=datz,mapping = aes(x = interaction(dnum,mon),y = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",width = 0.25)+ 
  scale_x_discrete(guide = "axis_nested",breaks = interaction(datz$dnum,datz$mon)[c(F,T)]) + 
  theme_classic() + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0),breaks = seq(0,150,10))+
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

**A more complicated sample**

If you need strictly even dates despite of days count in a monthh you can use this:

```
ggplot(data=datz,mapping = aes(x = interaction(dnum,mon),y = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",width = 0.25)+ 
  scale_x_discrete(guide = "axis_nested",
     breaks = interaction(datz$dnum[datz$dnum %% 2 == 0] ,datz$mon[datz$dnum %% 2 == 0])) + 
  theme_classic() + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0),breaks = seq(0,150,10))+
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

Here we have two consequent days skipped Aug., 31 and Sep., 1

**3rd Edition**

If we neen to add odd ticks and extend month bar to positions under even first and last days of the months (Aug., 31 and Sep., 1) we can do the following:

```
ggplot(data=datz,mapping = aes(x = interaction(dnum,mon),y = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",width = 0.25)+ 
  scale_x_discrete(guide = "axis_nested",
                   breaks = interaction(datz$dnum, datz$mon), # you can remove this line (in this case) or use it to specify user defined ticks vector
                   labels = datz %>%                          # and set labels only
                     rowwise() %>% 
                     transmute(brl = paste0(ifelse(dnum %% 2 == 0, dnum, " "), ".", mon)) %>% 
                     pull
                   ) + 
  theme_classic() + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0),breaks = seq(0,150,10))+
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, can you make the ticks appear for the even numers?

Comment: I had interpreted the OP as _removing_ 2, 4, 6, etc, though the method for that is as straight-forward as what you've done here (reversed, for `[c(F,T)]`).

Comment: @r2evans thank you. I've edited the post. At first I thought they wanded to keep odd dates

Comment: @forecaster Please see the edited post

Comment: @r2evans I've added a more complicated sample retaining even days selection despite of days count in a previous month

Comment: Thanks so much again. This is what I need, however the ticks are missing, for odd #s, is there a way to add to ticks. I’ll accept this as an answer

Comment: @forecaster please see the 3rd edition of my answer